# Javascript onclick parameter

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a question about `"onclick"`  function in JavaScript. Here I have a div `"InfoBar"`

```
<div id="InfoBar"><br>
```

and two for loop

```
 var src = new Array();

 for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    src.push("el1","el2");
 }

 for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    doesFileExist(src[j]);
 }
```

and a doesFileExist() and klick function

```
function klick(el){
    alert(el)
}

function doesFileExist(urlToFile){
    document.getElementById('InfoBar').innerHTML += '<br>' + '<a id="css" onclick="klick(urlToFile)" href="#" title="'+urlToFile+'">' + "link1 : "  + urlToFile + '</a>';
}
```

now I've added a `"onclick"` function in `"a href"`.

if I click on "link1:el1", I want to display as alert `"urlToFile"` string.
But I doesn't work.

In `"a href"` `title="'+urlToFile+'"` it works perfect, but in `"onclick"` doesn't work.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the alert in klick fire? My suspicion is that you're klick function is expecting "el" which isn't defined when it's called via the event

Comment: Post the code of your `klick(urlToFile)` function or create a [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Ids have to be **unique** - `id="css"` is set at least twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating an attribute. That gets converted back into a function but the scope is broken.

- Don't use intrinsic event attributes.
- Minimise use of globals
- Avoid generating HTML by mashing strings together (at best it is hard to read, at worst you get this sort of issue)

Use standard DOM:

```
var container = document.getElementById('InfoBar');
container.innerHTML = ""; // Delete any existing content
container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('id', 'css'); // You are running this function is a loop and creating duplicate ids. Use a class instead.
anchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    klick(urlToFile); // the local variable urlToFile is still in scope
});
anchor.setAttribute('href', '#'); // Why are you linking to the top of the page? Use a <button>
anchor.setAttribute('title', urlToFile);
anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode("link1 : " + urToFile));
container.appendChild(anchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Event handles assigned this way won't work. You have to use JavaScript event handles. Means, you must create a new 'a' element, then bind a click event to it, and then append it as a child to the parent node. All this stuff is very good described on the web out there.